# Передача переменной в базовый шаблон при изменении url

Tags: python, jinja2

Необходимо из jinja2 передать переменную в базовый шаблон. Если вызов функции test на python происходит по url, то все работает корректно. Но необходимо вызывать функцию send_user_login_status при любом изменении url. В таком случае - не работает.
Как сделать, так, чтобы функция send_user_login_status срабатывала при любом изменении url и отправляла переменные с помощью jinja2. Используется фреймворк flask.

base.html - базовый шаблон

```
<li class="{{ login_status_class }}"> {{ login_status }}</li>
```

test.html - тестовая страница

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
```

Функция на python - работает

```
@app.route('/test')
def test_api():
    login_status_class = 'login'
    login_status = u'Enter'
    return render_template("base.html",
                                login_status=login_status,
                                login_status_class=login_status_class)
```

Функция на python - не работает

```
def send_user_login_status():
    login_status_class = 'login'
    login_status = u'Enter'
    return render_template("base.html",
                           login_status=login_status,
                           login_status_class=login_status_class)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Как сделать, так, чтобы функция send_user_login_status срабатывала при
>   любом изменении url и отправляла переменные с помощью jinja2.

Можно использовать декоратор @app.url_value_preprocessor, который будет запускать нужную функцию сразу после формирования запроса.
А нужные переменные можно передавать через g.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, g
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', defaults={'path': ''})
@app.route('/<path:path>')
def test(path):
    return render_template("base.html",
                                login_status=g.login_status,
                                login_status_class=g.login_status_class)

@app.url_value_preprocessor
def send_user_login_status(endpoint, values):
    g.login_status_class = u'login'
    g.login_status = u'Enter'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Подробнее здесь: [Using URL Processors](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/appcontext/).

Comment: В таком случае возникает дублирование кода. Не подскажите, как его избежать?https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/786374/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B2-flask

Comment: @lipton_v, вы имеете ввиду передачу значений в шаблон? Получить значения можно прямо из шаблона: **<li class="{{ g.login_status_class }}"> {{ g.login_status }}</li>**. Тогда функция test будет возвращать лишь: **return render_template("base.html")**.

Comment: Если честно, не понимаю зачем вызывать функцию send_user_login_status при каждом запросе, если можно проверить статус единожды при авторизации и передать его в flask.session.