# Как избежать дублирование кода в Flask

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

Пытаюсь изменить некоторые переменные в базовом html шаблоне, от которого наследуются другие html страницы, после того, как пользователь заходит в личный кабинет.

Идея в следующем:

- Существует базовый html шаблон и в нем в зависимости от статуса пользователя (залогинен или нет) отображаются кнопки `Registration` и `Enter`/`Exit`.
- Если пользователь залогинен, то я хочу, чтобы кнопка `Enter` и `Registration` исчезали и вместо кнопки `Enter` появлялась кнопка `Exit`
- Если пользователь не залогинен, то должны быть две кнопки: `Enter` and `Registration`

Я сделал это при помощи  flask, jinja2 и python, но бэкэнд код выглядит ужасно, потому что очень много дублирования есть.

Я имею ввиду следующее:

Вот эта функция запускается перед тем, как юзеру отображается какая-либо html страница

```
from flask import g
from flask import render_template
@app.url_value_preprocessor
def send_user_login_status(endpoint, values):
    if current_user.is_authenticated: # if logged in
        g.login_button_class = u'logout'
        g.login_button = u'Exit'         

        g.signin_button = u''
        g.signin_button_class = u'signout'
    else: # if not logged in
        g.login_button_class = u'login'
        g.login_button = u'Enter'


        g.signin_button = u'Registration'
        g.signin_button_class = u'signin'

    return render_template("base.html",
                           login_button=g.login_button,                               
                           login_button_class=g.login_button_class,
                           signin_button=g.signin_button,
                           signin_button_class=g.signin_button_class,
                           )
```

И теперь мне нужно каждый раз передавать переменные в html, чтобы на этой html странице отображались нужные кнопки

Главная страница

```
@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template("index.html",
                           login_button=g.login_button,                                                           
                           login_button_class=g.login_button_class,
                           signin_button=g.signin_button,
                           signin_button_class=g.signin_button_class,                           
                           )
```

страница *о нас*

```
@app.route('/about')
def about():
    # send_user_login_status()
    return render_template("about.html",
                           login_button=g.login_button,                            
                           login_button_class=g.login_button_class,
                           signin_button=g.signin_button,
                           signin_button_class=g.signin_button_class,
                         )
```

И питон функция для разлогинизации пользователя

```
@app.route('/logout', methods=['POST'])
def logout():
    login_status = logout_user()
    if login_status:
        g.login_button_class = u'login'
        g.login_button = u'Enter'


        g.signin_button = u'Registration'
        g.signin_button_class = u'signin'


        jsonify({'result': True})
        return redirect('/')
```

**Как видите слишком много дублирования, потому что мне каждый раз нужно передавать значения переменных, которые зависят от того, залогинен пользователь или нет**

При этом html код выглядит хорошо:

base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
</head>

<body>
         <nav id="menu">
          <ul class="right">
                    <li class="{{ login_button_class }}"> {{ login_button }}</li>
                    <li class="{{ signin_button_class }}">{{ signin_button }}</li>
                </ul>
         </nav>
         <main>

                {% block content %}
                {% endblock %}
         </main>

</body>
```

index.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
 <h1>Home</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

about.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
 <h1>About</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Попробуйте написать собственную функцию декоратор для этого...

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! А не подскажете, как это сделать? Дело в том, что декоратор ведь меняет поведение функции, а здесь мне фактически надо изменить вывод..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я в итоге сделал вот так:

```
def render_sidebar_template(tmpl_name, **kwargs):
    if current_user.is_authenticated:  # если залогинен
        trigger_logged_id()
    else:  # иначе
        trigger_logged_out()
    return render_template(tmpl_name,
                           login_button=g.login_button,
                           login_sidebar_class=g.login_sidebar_class,
                           login_button_class=g.login_button_class,
                           signin_button=g.signin_button,
                           signin_button_class=g.signin_button_class,
                           signin_sidebar_class=g.signin_sidebar_class,
                           personal_account=g.personal_account,
                           **kwargs)
```

Теперь вместо return render_template(...) возвращаю верхнюю функцию:

```
@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_sidebar_template("index.html")
```

Answer (score 2):

Получить значение из g можно прямо из шаблона:

```
<li class="{{ g.login_button_class }}"> {{ g.login_button }}</li>
<li class="{{ g.signin_button_class }}">{{ g.signin_button }}</li>
```

Тогда render_template достаточно передать только название шаблона:

```
@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template("index.html")
```